# Control when the edition has finished in a DevExpress data-grid

Tags: datagrid, controls, devexpress

I am using AngularJS to implement a DevExpress control on my website. This control is of type dx-data-grid.

The control works perfectly but I run into a problem. In the mesh I have a series of records that I want to modify. I know how to control when editing starts (using the onEditingStart function) but my problem is that I do not know how to control when editing ends, because at that point I want to send the list to the server to modify it.

The View:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5iMB.png)

The function that controls the beginning of the edition is:

```js
                onEditingStart: function (e) {
                    console.debug("EditingStart");
                },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [rowUpdating](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#rowUpdating) or [rowUpdated](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#rowUpdated) event as per your requirement. At these events you can create list of records to pass to custom server side code.

If you require any further information then provide more information about the current implementation.

Hope this help

Comment: I want to send information to the server when everything is finished, and with the solution you offer I would have to call each time a line was modified and that's not good enough, but thanks.